# Swift 2 RAC4 Merge UITextField Signal and UISwitch Signal

Tags: ios, swift, merge, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-4

I've written a reactive-imperative version of the code:

```
widthTextField.rac_textSignal().subscribeNext { (val) in
    let multiplier = 0.2
    if var v = Double(val as! String){
        if(self.viewModel.proportionalBool.value){
            v *= multiplier
            self.heightTextField.text = String(v)
        }
    }
}
```

What I have in my ViewModel are three MutableProperties: proportionalBool of type Bool, heightString and widthString of type String.

I also have a corresponding UISwitch and two UITextFields in my ViewController.

What I wish to learn is having the following scenario:
1. If bool/switch is false, then heightString should be untouched
2. If bool is true, then heightString should be a value of: widthString * multiplier

I know I've written the code in a bad way. I think I should have used combineLatest but I have no idea how to merge two signals: UITextField and UISwitch into one producing signal.

Could anyone give me any hint or a simple code example?

```
let boolSignal = proportionalSwitch.rac_newOnChannel()
let widthSignal = widthTextField.rac_textSignal()
let heightSignal = heightTextField.rac_textSignal()
...?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you want always want to have the MutableProperties in your ViewModel always have the correct values.

Also I'm going to use [REX](https://github.com/neilpa/Rex/tree/master/Source) ([which will soon be a part of RAC anyway](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/2790)) for simpler UI Bindings.

Lets say this is your viewModel:

```
final class ViewModel {
    let on = MutableProperty<Bool>(false)
    let width = MutableProperty<Double>(0.0)
    let height = MutableProperty<Double>(0.0)
}
```

The first part is binding the switch and the textfields to the MutableProperties of your viewModel.

The first two are relatively straight forward:

```
viewModel.on <~ onSwitch.rex_on
viewModel.width <~ widthTextField.rex_textSignal
    .map { Double($0) ?? 0 }
```

Note: I've chosen to send 0 as width if the input of the width textfield is not a valid number. Depending on your needs, you might want to handle this case differently, e.g. by having the `width` and `height` properties have optional values...

Now the height is almost the same, but we have to make sure its only processed while the switch is **on**. This is achieved by using `combineLatest` and `filter`:

```
viewModel.height <~ combineLatest(viewModel.on.producer, viewModel.width.producer)  // SignalProducer<(Bool, Double), NoError>
    .filter { on, text in return on }   // Only send values when the switch is `on`
    .map { on, width in return width }  // Now we dont care about the switch value anymore, extract just the width
    .map { width in return 0.5 * width }// Transform the width as you wish
```

Now, all thats left is to bind the value of the height to the UI. Unless I'm missing something, theres no help from REX for that (at least not for `UITextField`), so we'll have to use a `DynamicProperty`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Previously mentioned binding to the viewModel

    DynamicProperty(object: heightTextField, keyPath: "text") <~ viewModel.height.producer.map { String($0) }
}
```

Comment: That's amazing MeXx! Thank you!